# Error in VSCode for Windows using Linux header

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, header-files, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using VS Code on Windows 10 and have written some C code. In the code, I need to use the `sys/wait.h` header. Since that is a Linux-specific header, I need to compile and run with WSL2 using Ubuntu as a subsystem.

The code compiles and works with WSL but VS Code gives me the following error:

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath.

My guess is it's because my current `includePath` points to GCC on my Windows machine and not to WSL, which is why it can't find this header. Is there a way for me to also include the headers found in WSL Ubuntu or do I have to live with this annoying error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the WSL/Linux `gcc` and Linux headers/libraries from within VSCode::

1. Install either the "WSL - Remote" extension or the "Remote Development" extension pack in VSCode.
2. Either:

   - From within WSL, `cd` to your project directory and then start VSCode with `code .`.
   - Start VSCode from Windows and click the *"Open a Remote Window"* button at the bottom left of the screen.  It looks like a `>` `<` stacked together.  Then select *"Open Folder in WSL ..."*.  This is also available from the Command Palette (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) with *"Remote WSL - Open Folder in WSL ..."*

Comment: This worked, thanks for the help. The only problem I got was that it could not find stdio.h, which I solved by moving my workspace folder to the WSLs memory-space.